# one index page with four div pages instead of four seperate .html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a jQuery page and dealt with multiple pages using  and jQuery on local folder on one index.html without a bother.

Now I'm doing this on CSS3 and HTML5 more and use jQuery 1.7 for features and functions. So I've more control for style rather than depending 100% on jQuery layout.

For example:
One index page with four div pages instead of four separate index.html

On jQuery index.html you have for index page

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="a" >
  <?php include("php/header1.php"); ?>
      <!--End HEADER -->
      <div data-role="content">
          <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>   
   <?php include("php/footer_front.php"); ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Start Page two--> 
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <?php include("php/header2.php"); ?>
      <!--End HEADER --> 
      <!-- Start Collapsible Block widget-->
      <div data-role="content">
          Content here for page two
      </div>
      <!-- END Collapsible Block widget--> 
    <?php include("php/footer_front.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- End Page two--> 

  <!-- Start Page Three--> 
  <div data-role="page" id="page3">
  <?php include("php/header3.php"); ?>
      <!--End HEADER --> 
      <!-- Start Collapsible Block widget-->
      <div data-role="content">
          Content here for page two
      </div>
      <!-- END Collapsible Block widget--> 
    <?php include("php/footer_front.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- End Page Three--> 

  <!-- Start Page Four--> 
  <div data-role="page" id="page4">
  <?php include("php/header4.php"); ?>
      <!--End HEADER --> 
      <!-- Start Collapsible Block widget-->
      <div data-role="content">
          Content here for page two
      </div>
      <!-- END Collapsible Block widget--> 
    <?php include("php/footer_front.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- End Page Three-->
```

But it doesn't work as it should with index page on its own and click page two for new clean page two? Instead I see index page, page 2 and page 3 and page 4 all on one browser window>

How do I separate the pages instead of all on one browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we have all the information here, but if you want separate pages without a refresh by using jQuery, then you should have a place holder for where all your main content of the pages will go, then in your index only have the code for the first page's content. when you click on page 2 then use jQuery to remove the html inside of the main-content container by using .html() and replace it with the html of the new page 2. Best way of doing this is by using AJAX. If you do not know what that is you should do a fast Google search and read up on what AJAX is and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Fernando. Do you have examples or tutorial that you can recommend? So I can Google better. It is for iphone app (html).